# Replacement for chrome.tabs.onUpdated

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I write extension for google chrome, and i need to monitor change of url. 
I simply use chrome.tabs.onUpdated event, but it's work only when i reload page.

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (
          tab.url.match(/localhost/) ||
          tab.url.match(/.../) ||
          tab.url.match(/.../)
          ) {
    chrome.pageAction.show(tabId);
  }
});
```

Some pages in this sites update url by pressing button in page without reloading page, and this event doesn't work.

Of cource, by pressing button and modified url in site appears new content

Any ideas of new event, which handle with this problem?

Comment: chrome.tabs.onUpdated sees any URL changes regardless of whether the page was reloaded or not so the problem must be something else: maybe the site doesn't actually change the URL, in which case you can use MutationObserver, see also [Is there a JavaScript / jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: It's also possible that the new URL is only present in `changeInfo.url` so try using `const url = changeInfo.url || tab.url`